# Want to Cut background image of canvas circle

Tags: java, android, bitmap, crop

Want to Cut background image of  canvas circle

```
canvas.drawBitmap(background_image, 0, 0, null);            
FaceDetector.Face face = faces[0];
tmp_paint.setColor(Color.RED);
`face.getMidPoint(tmp_point);
canvas.drawCircle(tmp_point.x, tmp_point.y, face.eyesDistance(), tmp_paint);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function:

```
public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) {
    int targetWidth = 125;
    int targetHeight = 125;

    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth,
            targetHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(
            ((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
            ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
            (Math.min(((float) targetWidth), ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
            Path.Direction.CCW);
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
    canvas.drawBitmap(
            sourceBitmap,
            new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight()), 
            new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), 
            p);
    return targetBitmap;
}
```

For more details check this : http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2012/09/crop-image-in-circular-shape-in-android.html

Comment: What is "p" in

  new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap
                        .getHeight()), new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth,
                        targetHeight), p);

is this a path???????

Comment: p is the paint's object